# What did The Accountant do wrong?

Tags: character, the-accountant

What did The Accountant go to prison for?

He was in Leavenworth if I'm not mistaken, the only thing I can remember is the fight at the funeral, that shouldn't get you sent to Leavenworth

Comment: If he's convicted of an offence under the UCMJ regulations...he could be sent to Leavenworth. What that was I don't recall that being mentioned....but someone died and he was 'involved'....so there's that.

Comment: That does bring up an interesting though, I over looked the military uniform, could someone with Asperger's even get in the military?

Comment: His dad was a Colonel...strings could have been pulled. However, it's not made clear **why** Wolff is in jail. It could be because of the funeral melee or something that happened afterward.